# Why I can't select sibling tag beside an input in TailwindCSS?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Here is my code:

```html
<input
  type='text'
  className='[&:focus + span]:bg-black border-b-2 border-dark10 px-24 py-16 focus:border-dark100'
/>
<span className='absolute left-0 top-1/2 ml-24 -translate-y-1/2 select-none text-16 font-normal text-dark40'>
  Test
</span>
```

I have used `[&:focus + span]:bg-black` to change the `span` background when the `input` element is focused. It doesn't work. What is my mistake?

Comment: Can you point to the part of the documentation explains why you think `[&:focus + span]:bg-black` will help?

Comment: (As usual when confronted by tailwind's massive list of obscure class names I'm left wondering why people don't just write CSS)

Comment: @Quentin I found this in another question. I checked it in other ways and it worked.

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spaces delimit class names, so `[&:focus + span]:bg-black` would be treated as `[&:focus`, `+` and `span]:bg-black`, neither of which are valid Tailwind class names.

Consider removing the spaces to `[&:focus+span]:bg-black`:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.5"></script>

<input
  type='text'
  class='[&:focus+span]:bg-black border-b-2 border-dark10 px-24 py-16 focus:border-dark100'
/>
<span class='absolute left-0 top-1/2 ml-24 -translate-y-1/2 select-none text-16 font-normal text-dark40'>
  Test
</span>
```